# Determine how many subgroup of $G$ if the cardinality given

Tags: abstract-algebra, group-theory

> If $G$ is a group and $|G| = 2018$, then how many subgroup of $G$, let's say $H$, such that $|H| = 12$?

I don't quick and theorized ways to determine how many subgroup if the cardinality given. Lagrange Theorem connects factor group, not in this case. Do you have any idea? Regards.

Comment: $2018$ is not divisible by $12$, hence there is no subgroup.

Comment: What theorem do you use? Does the division result show how many subgroup?

Answer (score 4):

Lagrange's Theorem states that if $H$ is a subgroup of a finite group $G$, then the order $|H|$ divides $|G|$. Since $12$ does not divide $2018$, there cannot be any subgroup of order $12$, i.e. the answer is $0$.

Comment: if $x$ divides the cardinality, then the result indicates how many subgroup with x elements?

Comment: No, in general Lagrange's theorem does not tell the number of subgroups. But in this case (i.e. when $|H|=12$ and $|G|=2018$) it does tell the number because it tells you the inexistence of such a subgroup.

Comment: So we actually don't have some ways to determine it?

Comment: As far as I know there is no result in full generality. But for some special cases when $H$ is a $p$-group for some prime $p$ or when $G$ itself is a $p$-group, there are many results that I know.